# No data after tiling a satellite imagery using gdal.Translate

Tags: python, gdal

I have a satellite imagery with these properties:

```
Extent  472596.0000000000000000,3942138.0000000000000000 : 511680.0000000000000000,3970161.0000000000000000
Width   13028
Height  9341
Data type   UInt16 - Sixteen bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description /home/johnny/datasets/planet_test_set_with_filtering/20220929_103205_35_247b.tiff
Compression LZW
```

I split this image into tiles of 256x256 using gdal.Translate method in Python:

```py
kwargs_gdal = {
    'format': 'PNG',
    'xRes': 3,
    'yRes': 3,
    'outputType': gdal.GDT_Byte,
}
    
gdal.Translate(
    output,
    gdal.Open(mimages),
    projWin=([ulx, uly, lrx, lry]),
    bandList=([6, 4, 2]),
    scaleParams=[[]],
    **kwargs_gdal,
)
```

I need the output to be in png and byte format so I can label it in labelImg.
Yet, even though in the initial imagery there is no no_data in it, when I convert it the output may be look like this:
[image]

even though the initial part of the image looks like this:
[image]

Something happens during conversion, does anybody know what exactly is going on?

Comment: Does gdalinfo report also that bands have 0 as nodata value?

Comment: It is normal that small UInt16 numbers scale into 0 when they are converted into 8 bit. But I can't say why 0 is interpreted to mean NoData if you have not asked for that.

Comment: even though there are no no_data values in the initial imagery, in the tile imagery qgis mentions that, NODATA_VALUES=0 0 0. I am thinking to state that the output no_data values to have a constant value.

Comment: And for a confirmation, does gdalinfo report something like `Band 1 Block=300x9 Type=Byte ...
  NoData Value=0...`

Comment: No it does not. What does this mean?

Comment: If gdalinfo does not report nodata then the image does not have nodata stored into the metadata. If QGIS still shows that band values `0 0 0` are nodata then they have been set by QGIS. Then the fix is to tell QGIS that zero means just zero, not nodata. If you could share your image it would make it much easier to help.

Comment: here is a tile that I have been assigned to it the no data value of 1 in each band. neveretheless, if one open it in qgis there are also no_data values. why is that?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nThkkJA-uQlT_9NUdp13gxIYT0FRpY7r/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I do not understand. You say you haven assigned nodata values 1 for each band and QGIS shows `NODATA_VALUES=1 1 1` for me. Does it show something else for you?